# Zooming to layer extent using PyQGIS when project SCR and layer SCR are not the same

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I'm creating a plugin to automate maps layout and I obviously need to use the extent of my main layer for this...

If my layer SCR and my project SCR were the same I would simply proceed this way:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
ext = layer.extent()

iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(ext)
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

But since my QGIS SCR is set-up to 'EPSG:2154' and my layer to 'EPSG:4326' I tried this:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
crsSrc = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326") 
crsDest = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:2154") 
transformContext = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest, transformContext)

# forward transformation: src -> dest
layer2154 = xform.transform(layer)

new_extent = layer_2154.extent()
iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(new_extent)
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

But unfortunately it is not working :/

Comment: You can't transform a layer object. In this case, you need to transform the layer extent (a `QgsRectangle` object). Try: `new_extent = xform.transform(layer.extent())` *Delete the line: `layer2154 = xform.transform(layer)` See: https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateTransform.html#aefa41b71beec7d5e46dfd4d04655fc4a

Comment: Awesome, thank you Ben ! You can post this as an answer